# How to use mongoose updateMany middleware to increase performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, middleware, mongoose-schema

**SOLVED: SOLUTION AT THE BOTTOM**

I have the following Code where I am updating element by element:

```js
//registerCustomers.js
const CustomerRegistrationCode = require("../models/CustomerRegistrationCode");

const setRegCodesToUsed = async (regCodes) => {
  for (let regCode of regCodes) {
    await setRegCodeToUsed(regCode._id);
  }
};

const setRegCodeToUsed = async (id) => {
  await CustomerRegistrationCode.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { used: true });
};
```

The Code works fine but is to slow and i want to update many (1000) CustomerRegistrationCodes at once.
I had a look at the updateMany middleware function but found not much info online and on the official docs. I changed my code to the following but don't know how further.

```js
//registerCustomers.js
const setRegCodesToUsed = async (regCodes) => {
  await CustomerRegistrationCode.updateMany(regCodes);
}
```

```js
//CustomerRegistrationCode.js
CustomerRegistrationCodeSchema.pre('updateMany', async function (next, a) {
  console.log('amount arguments: ', arguments.length); //is 2
  console.log(arguments); //both parameters are functions.
  next();
});
```

What would be the best way to update many CustomerRegistrationCodes with 1000 different id's?

**SOLUTION, thanks to Murat Colyaran**

```js
const setRegCodesToUsed = async (regCodes) => {
  const ids = [];
  regCodes.map(code => ids.push(code._id));
  await setRegCodeToUsed(ids);
};

const setRegCodeToUsed = async (ids) => {
  await CustomerRegistrationCode.updateMany(
    { _id: { $in: ids } },
    { used: true }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
//registerCustomers.js
const CustomerRegistrationCode = require("../models/CustomerRegistrationCode");

const setRegCodesToUsed = async (regCodes) => {
    let ids = [];
    regCodes.map((code) => ids.push(code._id.toString()));
    await setRegCodeToUsed(ids);
};

const setRegCodeToUsed = async (ids) => {
    await CustomerRegistrationCode.updateMany(
        { 
            id : { $in: ids }
        },
        {
            used: true
        }
    );
};
```

Instead of sending a query for every records, we just parse the `id` and send a bulk request with `$in`

Comment: I have to say: Murat.insertMany(thanks). I had to change the id parameter to _id and i post the improved post here :)

Comment: @swftowu69 Glad to hear. Your welcome!